# fgets stuck when reading from an external process pipe

Tags: c++, linux, popen, fgets, iperf3

I'm calling `iperf3` from via `popen` and read from its output into a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string peer_ip = "localhost";

  string iperf_cmd = "iperf3 -c " + peer_ip + " -t 1" + " -R 2>&1";
  string iperf_out;
  char iperf_buff[2];

  FILE *iperf_d = popen(iperf_cmd.c_str(), "r");
  while (fgets(iperf_buff, 2, iperf_d) != nullptr)
    iperf_out += iperf_buff;
  pclose(iperf_d);

  cout << iperf_out << "\n";
}
```

This works most of the time.

However, when the network is is very slow, my `fgets` gets stuck and program never prints the output from `iperf3`. Why is that?

From `man fgets(3)`:

> fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
> and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading  stops
> after  an EOF  or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into
> the buffer. A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last
> character  in the buffer.

Note that my buffer is 2 bytes long.

Comment: Are you sure that it's `fgets` that is stuck, and not the `iperf3`?

Comment: @VladFeinstein How would you check that in this program? I mean, I can forcibly interrupt `iperf3` by adding `timeout 2` in front of `iperf_cmd`. That will "unstuck" `iperf3`, but what if I cannot come up with any reasonable timeout for determining that `iperf3` is stuck?

Comment: what happens if you simply run that `iperf3 -c localhost -t 1 -R` on that slow network?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Well, it all runs repeatedly on a real network with significant real-time variations. Unfortunately, I don't have an emulator in which I could reproduce the network conditions. What I know for sure is that the program gets stuck (from my logs). My point is that there is no (easy) way for me to tell whether `fgets` or the process itself gets stuck using the `popen` and `fgets` API that Linux exposes. Or, am I wrong?